# Multer nodejs - req.file is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am creating an app using Node, Express and ejs and multer for uploading images. Every time I submit the form, req.file is undefined. I've spent the entire day troubleshooting but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
<form action="/post" id="formPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input class="img-file" type="file" name="image" required>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'resources/views'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());   
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./image");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req.file);

    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.fieldname + ".png");
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/post", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.file);
});
app.get("/post", (req, res) => {
  res.render("post");
});
app.listen(, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000/login`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few little bugs: first you forgot to add `port` and instead of `login` it should be `post` then we hit the correct address immediately, avoiding error `Cannot GET /login`

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000/post`);
});
```

---

*Project Folder & File structure*:

[image]

---

**app.js** I added simple an error handler to the:

```
app.post("/post", upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {}
```

---

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "resources/views"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./image");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req.file);

    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.fieldname + ".png");
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// app.post("/post", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
//   console.log(req.file);
// });

app.post("/post", upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file;
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
    error.httpStatusCode = 400;
    return next(error);
  }
  res.send(file);
  console.log("Success", req.file);
});

app.get("/post", (req, res) => {
  res.render("post");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000/post`);
});
```

---

**post.ejs**

```
<form action="/post" id="formPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="img-file" type="file" name="image" required />
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

---

*output:*

[image]

*after selecting the file and pressing upload file:*

[image]

VSCode output:

[image]

**Works like a charm ;-)**

---

Comment: @3305_TrầnĐìnhTrung You're welcome ! You can now mark my answer as useful and it's solved your problem ! Best regards ! and Keep on coding ;-)